# How to exclude subtree in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a simple tree graph in Neo4j. Each node is of type `Object`, has `id` and `name` properties, and can be linked by parent-child `AGGREGATION` link with some other nodes (graph is a tree, no cycles allowed).

I successfully run a simple query that returns a particular subtree (rooted by node with ID 127 in the example below):

```
MATCH network = (:Object { id: 127 })-[*]->()
RETURN network
```

But I need a query, that also excludes a subtree, rooted by a specified node (say 131), from the subtree returned by a query above. How does this query look like?

(I tried:

```
MATCH network = (:Object { id: 127 })-[*]->(x:Object)
WHERE x.id <> 131
RETURN network
```

, this only excludes a single node if it doesn't have children.

```
MATCH network = (:Object { id: 127 })-[*]->(x:Object)-[*]->()
WHERE x.id <> 131
RETURN network
```

, also doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way through list comprehensions

```
MATCH network = (:Object { id: 127 })-[*]->(x:Object)
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(network) WHERE n.id = 131)
RETURN network
```

This works pretty fast, but maybe better solutions exist?...